# Python Image.crop saves black images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make tiles for a game using a larger background image and cropping them, but after saving the first 17 images I start running into problems. The 18th image is blackened out at the bottom and the remaining images are all black.  Any thoughts?

Here is my code. imagesize=(512, 512), tilesize=(32, 32)

```
def __init__(self, path, imagesize, tilesize):
    self.tiles = dict()
    self.backimage = Image.open(path)
    self.backimage.resize(imagesize)
    self.x = imagesize[0]/tilesize[0]
    self.y = imagesize[1]/tilesize[1]
    currx = 0
    curry = 0
    for i in range(self.x):
        for j in range(self.y):
            tmp = path + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".png"
            self.tiles[(i, j)] = tmp
            image = self.backimage.crop((currx, curry, currx+tilesize[0], curry+tilesize[1]))
            image.save(tmp, "PNG")

            curry += tilesize[1]
        currx += tilesize[0]
```

Comment: I'm sure this user would post an image, but doesn't have enough reputation. (+1)

Comment: I'd expected your problem to be at the 16th and 17th images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not resetting `curry` at the end of the `j` loop. It just keeps increasing until it's out of bounds.